# Eve with Postman "must be of list type" error

Tags: python, postman, eve

I have an eve schema set up as such:

```
schema = {
  "month": {
    "type": "datetime",
    "required": True,
  },

  "test": {
    "type": "list"
  },
}
```

And I'm using postman to make a post request:

[image]

I'm at a bit of a loss here as to why I'm getting this error, am I missing something glaringly obvious? Is that not the correct way to format a list for postman/eve?

Other fields work fine, datetimes, strings, integers, etc. But as soon as I try to post a list, no matter what I do I get this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the request being sent by Postman using `form-data` body, you can see that the body goes similar to this:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarynhX0dI6JZNPzq8AK
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="month"

2017-08-01T00:00:00
------WebKitFormBoundarynhX0dI6JZNPzq8AK
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="test"

[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
------WebKitFormBoundarynhX0dI6JZNPzq8AK--
```

Using raw body from Postman, and setting the Request-header `Content-type` to `application/json`, it goes like this, and works for eve:

```
{
  "month": "2017-08-01T00:00:00",
  "test": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
}
```

I can't give you a good explanation about why, but this is how I do to make it work with pyeve.

Comment: Yep. That sure did work. Thank you! I knew it was bound to be a simple answer.